# Harsh redirect back() Laravel5.2

Tags: php, laravel

I am having a small issue with my Laravel 5.2 application. The problem is with a page made to adjust database entries.

When data has been adjusted and a button is pressed to update the database, it works great. Problem is, I would like to redirect `back()` to the previous page, but this page has been set up through data from other pages.

So when I redirect back, it error's and says that certain parameters are not defined. Is there a option, that I can implement a very static redirect to the previous page and all the data that has been loaded in the page?
Like the `go back` function that web browsers have?

**Solution**

I added the following code in the Controller function where the page is made to adjust the database entry:

```
Session::flash('url',Request::server('HTTP_REFERER'));
```

And as a redirect I have this:

```
return Redirect::to(Session::get('url'));
```

Comment: Consider using AJAX request to update the information. It looks like it's the best choice in this case.

Comment: Hi, I have absolute no knowledge about AJAX so I am trying to avoid this.

Comment: Sounds like a good opportunity to learn it to be honest

Comment: I have found a solution! I will update my question.

Comment: If you would like to share it I am curious! @Ale

Comment: @AnnaJeanine, sorry, I wanted to share another kind of solution (using sessions). But if your code in updated answer works for you, it's a better solution.

Comment: Oke! Thank you @AlexeyMezenin